# SQL query I have a table name student with two columns name and status

Tags: sql

I have a table name student with two columns `name` and `status`

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  name varchar(30) , status varchar(30) 
);

INSERT INTO student 
(name, status) 
VALUES 
('a','pass'),
('a','fail'),
('a','pass'),
('b','fail'),
('b','fail'),
('b','pass');
```

Query should display 3 columns

```
name pass fail
a    2      1
b    1      2
```

i.e. the name of students corresponding to which count of no. of subjects they passed and number of subjects they failed in should be displayed in result.

Comment: -1 This isn't a question.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MYSQL? SQL is just the structured query language... ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
select name,
sum(case when status = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) as sumPass,
sum(case when status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as sumFail
From student
group by name
```

and the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7959/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this in MYSQL: (assuming you are using MYSQL, **not portable to** `Oracle, SQL Server`)

[MYSQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7959/3)

```
select name,
sum(status = 'pass') as Pass,
sum(status = 'fail') as Fail
From student
group by name
;

| NAME | PASS | FAIL |
----------------------------
|    a |       2 |       1 |
|    b |       1 |       2 |
```